# Rails 4 Validating associated model id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

Let's say I have a model `Book`

```
class Books < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
  has_many :pages
  validates :library_id, presence: true
end
```

And a model `Library`

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  belongs_to :city
end
```

How can I fix a nil exception I'm getting somewhere, NoMethodError undefined method `library` for nil:NilClass when I do something like `book.library`?

Or in other words how can I make sure that before linking a book to a library, the  `library_id` is not `nil` and it exists in the database? Shouldn't the `validates :library_id, presence: true` solve this already?

Comment: So cool I didn't even know you could get the parent object like that.  Yes, it should work as you say.  Can you provide some code and the specific error message with the line number?

Comment: You could also use `validates_presence_of :library_id`.  I'd also add to the Library a destroy clause: `has_many :books, dependent: :destroy`

Answer (score 1):

You have validated library_id. That's enough for books.
What you need to do is making sure libraries which have books can not be deleted.

Here is an example:

```
def destroy
  @library = Library.find params[:id]
  if @library.books.blank?
    @library.destroy
    redirect_to libraries_path
  else
    redirect_to library_path(@library)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `book.library` do a check `book.library if book.library`
Or add dependent destroy to Book model `has_many :books, dependent: :destroy`

Answer (score 1):

Before you calling `book.library` ,yous hould do a check on book :

```
book.library if book
```